# Vetores de inicialização Cordova + Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova

Sou novo em desenvolvimento com o AngularJS e estou começando a criar uma aplicação, onde antes de chegar até o login do usuário eu preciso validar se existe um banco de dados SQLite, se dentro do banco eu tenho o link do servidor e se no banco eu tenho a licença de uso.

Se fosse em um projeto com Jquery, eu simplesmente faria meu **index.html** executar as funções para identificar as condições acima (junto com um load ou algo do tipo) e se válido, direcionaria para uma segunda página html com a aplicação em si.

Alguém, por favor poderia me dar uma luz de como eu faço isso? porque eu gostaria de manter a estrutura do AngularJS (MVC) em todos os processos, sem fazer nenhum "recurso técnico"...

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

Basicamente, tenho uma página `default` que é chamada sempre que a aplicação é iniciada, a partir de então eu direciono o controlador desta página para fazer todos os tratamentos que são necessários e, a partir de então (dependendo dos resultados) eu redireciono o aplicativo para o `router` que é a resposta para as condições do controlador inicial.